# How to open files with emacs in new tabs

Tags: emacs

I normally open files in `emacs` with:

```
$ emacs file.txt &
```

But what really gets me crazy, is that eventually I have dozens of files - each one opened in a separate window and as a result navigation between them becomes a real nightmare. What I want is to open new files in new tabs (like the way browser opens sites in new tabs). But I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually opening each file in a DIFFERENT copy of `emacs`. Probably not the best usage of system resources.

In your `${HOME}/.emacs` file, ensure that you execute the `server-start` function as part of your `emacs` startup. Start `emacs` before the following

Then edit your files with:

```
# wait until you type ^X# in the emacs buffer
emacsclient file.txt

# do not wait  
emacsclient --no-wait file.txt
```

Rather than retrain my reflexes, I define an alias in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias emacs='emacsclient --alternate-editor /usr/bin/gvim'
```

and start my initial `emacs` with

```
/usr/bin/emacs24 &
```

or by clicking on an icon.